# Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 (Flutter and Dart)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications to a device token using this REST API but the notification is not being sent.
Is it perhaps the token is wrong?
I am not sure if access the bearer token is wron or not. May I be assisted please.

The method sendNotificationForTesting is being called using a button immediatly when a user.

```
static Future<void> sendNotificationForTesting(String deviceToken) async {
try {
  // Retrieve the access token
  String? token = await getAccessToken();

  // Ensure token is not null before proceeding
  if (token != null) {
    // Make HTTP POST request to send notification
    await http.post(
      Uri.parse(
          'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/academy/messages:send'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token' // Use the retrieved token here
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        "message": {
          "token": deviceToken,
          "notification": {
            "title": "Breaking News",
            "body": "New news story available."
          },
          "data": {"id": "1"},
          "android": {
            "notification": {
              "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
            },
          },
        }
      }),
    );

    // Notification sent successfully
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      msg: "Notification sent successfully",
      textColor: Colors.white,
    );
  } else {
    // Handle case where access token is null
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      msg: "Access token is null",
      textColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }
} catch (e) {
  // Handle any errors that occur during the process
  print("Failed to send Notification for testing: $e");
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    msg: "Failed to send notification: ${e.toString()}",
    textColor: Colors.white,
  );
} }
```

This is the code I use to get the Bearer access token from a signed in user using email and password when they register withing the application.

```
static Future<String?> getAccessToken() async {
try {
  // Get the current user
  User? user = _auth.currentUser;

  // Check if the user is signed in
  if (user != null) {
    // Get the access token for the user
    final idTokenResult = await user.getIdToken();
    accessToken = idTokenResult!;
    return accessToken;
  } else {
    // User is not signed in
    return null;
  }
} catch (e) {
  // Handle any errors that occur during the process
  print("Error getting access token: $e");
  return null;
} }
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: How are you creating a server token?

Comment: @Ayesha Iftikhar I am not using the server token in this case since the server Key is not supposed to be used. I am accessing the bearer token from the loggen in user. is that how it is supposed to be accessed?

Comment: bearer token is basically the server token, I was talking about. If you are creating this token right. It is suppose to work. But can you post the output logs as well.?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully thiss will save you some time as well.

ensure that you have all these installed firebase_messaging,
firebase_core, http googleapis_auth

Also, download the service account file from cloud firestore by following these steps...

Navigate to your project on cloud firebase

1. Select the gear icon (Project settings)
2. Select the service account tab
3. Generete the file 5.locate the file on you local pc or machine
4. finally, use those variables and fill the "FILL_UP" placeholder on getAccessToken method

   ```
    static Future<String> generateFCMAccessToken() async {
    try {
      /* get these details from the file you downloaded(generated)
          from firebase console
      */
      String type = "FILL_UP";
      String project_id = "FILL_UP";
      String private_key_id = "FILL_UP";
      String private_key = "FILL_UP";
      String client_email = "FILL_UP";
      String client_id = "FILL_UP";
      String auth_uri = "FILL_UP";
      String token_uri = "FILL_UP";
      String auth_provider_x509_cert_url = "FILL_UP";
      String client_x509_cert_url = "FILL_UP";
      String universe_domain = "FILL_UP";

      final credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({
        "type": type,
        "project_id": project_id,
        "private_key_id": private_key_id,
        "client_email": client_email,
        "private_key": private_key,
        "client_id": client_id,
        "auth_uri": auth_uri,
        "token_uri": token_uri,
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
        "client_x509_cert_url": client_x509_cert_url,
        "universe_domain": universe_domain
      });

      List<String> scopes = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"
      ];

      final client = await obtainAccessCredentialsViaServiceAccount(
          credentials, scopes, http.Client());
      final accessToken = client;
      Timer.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 59), (timer) {
        accessToken.refreshToken;
      });
      return accessToken.accessToken.data;
    } catch (e) {
      Reuse.logger.i("THis is the error: $e");
    }
    return "";
   ```

   }